# Why is Series.apply so fast on a column with Intervals?

Tags: python, pandas

I had always thought `Series.apply` was a loop over the rows and we know that DataFrame.apply(axis=1) has some horrible scaling https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/4333359.

But when trying to get the midpoint of a Series of `pandas._libs.interval.Interval` with a dtype of `category` I noticed that `Series.apply` seems to not be doing that at all and is as fast as something like `Series.map`

In the following example I try to get the midpoint of an Interval either by applying a lambda (should be slow?) or doing something I thought should be very fast (mapping the 3 intervals to their midpoints, looping over only the 3 unique intervals).

So what's going on, why is the `Series.apply` so fast, or perhaps the `map` is just very slow?

```
import perfplot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def apply_mid(s):
    return s.apply(lambda x: x.mid)

def map_mid(s):
    d = {x: x.mid for x in s.cat.categories}
    return s.map(d)

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: pd.cut(pd.Series(np.random.randint(1, 100, 3*n)), 3), 
    kernels=[
        lambda s: apply_mid(s),
        lambda s: map_mid(s),
    ],
    labels=['apply', 'map'],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(24)],
    equality_check=np.allclose,  
    xlabel='~len(df)'
)
```

[image]

Comment: I suspect `map` is slow here since it's mapping an interval. But good question.

Comment: @Erfan yeah, probably. I know that `map` is only optimized for some very specific inputs. But even just comparing `lambda x: x.mid` to a lambda that does something silly like `lambda x: 1` the `x.mid` seems to be doing something to be so fast

Comment: Weird, your code doesn't run on my system. Throw: `TypeError: Cannot cast CategoricalIndex to dtype float64`

Comment: @QuangHoang hmm weird. It worked on mine with both `0.25.0` and `1.0.0`

Comment: Nice question, looking forward to the answer. Gratz on 30k :)

Comment: Have you looked at the source code? (I'm not very familiar with it myself, unfortunately)